# Engagespot Bell icon not working in React app

Tags: reactjs

I added Engagespot SDK code to my index.html page. But, I get this error on the login page.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at t._showNotificationCenter (EngagespotSDK.2.0.js:1)
    at EngagespotSDK.2.0.js:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Engagespot on a SPA (Like React, Vue, etc) is a bit different as mentioned in this article - https://docs.engagespot.co/how-to-install-engagespot/how-to-set-up-engagespot-in-single-page-applications

The above error occurs when the script is unable to find an HTML element (Placeholder element) that you've configured in your account.

Usually, this happens in apps that have a login screen. The element may not exist on the login page, but only on the page that comes after the login screen.

To solve this, you need to make that the `Engagespot.init()` function is executed only on the page that has your placeholder element. So, you can remove this function from the main Engagespot SDK code that you have in your index.html. And, place it the mount life cycle of your placeholder element.

Comment: Engagespot now has better integration with React. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/@engagespot/react-component